# Extending Partition for Ubuntu: Shrinking D drive

Tags: partitioning

Currently, I'm running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to extend the partition for Ubuntu. So, in the Windows partition, can I shrink D drive instead of C? Thank you.

This is the order of my partition:
[sda1][sda2/C in windows][sda6 ext4/Ubuntu][sda7 swap][sda5/D in Windows][another partition]

As I've said earlier I want to take some space from D drive. If you see the order, there is Ubuntu swap in between. Based on one answers of this question (see below), it might cause problem if I'm not be careful with the partition that I plan to do.

So, can somebody suggests me the good thing to do. I'll appreciate if you give me the steps, because honestly I'm an average user who is really nervous on this thing.

Comment: Always mod the windows partition with a windows tool.

Comment: After shrinking the partition in Windows, should I do the same installation as I installed Ubuntu for the first time?

Comment: Partitioning can be complicated, but if the 2 partitions are adjacent, you should be able to go into windows and shrink a partition, then go into Ubuntu and use gparted to expand the Ubuntu partition into the newly freed space.  BACK UP ALL YOUR DATA FIRST, I can't emphasize that enough.

Comment: If the two partitions are not adjacent it gets a lot more complicated and I would not feel comfortable advising you.

Comment: I shrank C drive when I installed Ubuntu. And now, I want to extend the partition by taking some space from D drive. Is this what you meant with not adjacent?

Comment: I'm gonna add an answer to your question to try and explain because I need a picture.  Give me a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(dropped down from comments so I could use a picture)

Here is a picture from the Windows partitioning tool of the partitions on a pc.  Take a look at the middle drive (Windows calls it G).  My Ubuntu partition is the 482 G partition on that drive, the 3rd one.  If I shrank the first partition on that drive, the 1374 G one, I couldn't expand my Ubuntu partition into it, because there is a little 200M partition in the way.  I'd have to move that and it would get complicated.  Bottom line, the 1374 G and 482G partitions are not adjacent so shrinking one will not help me expand the other without jumping through a bunch of other hoops.

But on the bottom drive, the E and F partitions are adjacent.  If I shrink one it's easy to expand the other into the newly freed space because they touch each other.

ALWAYS BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST.  ONLY CHANGE WINDOWS PARTITIONS FROM WITHIN WINDOWS.

[image]

Comment: If my Ubuntu partition and D partition, from which I want to take the extension, are separated by Ubuntu swap partition, will it be okay? Sorry for keep asking question.

Comment: This would be where I get uncomfortable advising you.  If they are like [ubuntu][swap][D] I think you would have to move the swap partition before expanding Ubuntu after you shrank D, but the only time I tried something like that, I broke the system and had to rebuild it.  So I am not comfortable telling you what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That makes no sense in Ubuntu. Open the partitioner, shrink the D: partition and install Ubuntu on the freed space.